# Accepted answers by self?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, asking-questions, self-answer

In [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394779/override-activerecord-get-properties-in-yii) the accepted answer is from the OP.

Under what conditions is that possible?

Comment: It's entirely possible to accept your own answer. You just won't get reputation from the acceptance.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, I was looking for that. ;)

Comment: any and all conditions.

Comment: It's fairly common for someone to post a question, then discover the answer themselves in the course of further investigating their problem.  In such a situation it only makes sense for them to answer their own question.

Answer (score 11):

You need to have posted an answer to the question, and you need to have waited 48 hours to allow others to attempt to answer.  After that, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Jeff doesn't work at SE anymore.  He left a while back.  Yes, it is possible for these requirements to change in the future (although you'd have to work pretty hard to have an accepted answer to a question you have not posted an answer to) and additional constraints could be added.  I don't know why you would be surprised that the company that owns the site could change how it functions.  It's of course their job to do such things.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Or, you can let the community take a stab at doing a better job than you did at trying to solve the problem, and give them a few days to chew on it. And while Jeff is far from perfect, I don't quite think he's the mono-black tyrannical monster you're comparing him to.